# split function (list index out of range)

Tags: python

```
textData = "SENDER|%|SUB|%|HTML|%|username{*|*}password{*|*}mail{*|*}data1|*|username{*|*}password{*|*}mail{*|*}data1"
genelData = textData.split("|%|")
userData = genelData[3].split("|*|")
for userDataTable in userData:
    usersData = userDataTable.split("{*|*}")
    self.response.out.write("<br>" + usersData[2])
```

in this code i try to parse some string data.But when i try to print "usersData" variable everything looks fine.But when i tried to use like "usersData[2]" im getting list index out of range problem.

Comment: Please show code that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure? For me it prints `<br>mail\n<br>mail' on Python 2.7.2

Comment: I run your code, except changing the very last line to `print usersData[2]` I worked fine?

Comment: i dont understand why its happening.im getting   

    self.response.out.write("<br>" + usersData[2])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: What happens if you try `self.response.out.write("fred")`?  Maybe we're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: it writes "fred" on screen. when i try print usersData[2] it works fine.But i cant use this variable in no where.

Comment: I founded problem.

i am adding "|%|" char to end of all lines in string file.when python tries to split them into pieces python trying to split last null string.

for that reason python giving me this error.i changed my code to 

        for userDataTable in userData:
            if len(userDataTable) > 0:


now everything looks fine.thanks again

Comment: @Korcan: Do not post your solution as a comment.  Please post a proper **Answer** to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should re-evaluate some of your identifiers...having 'userData' and 'usersData' in the same scope is a recipe for trouble.

Having said that, are you sure you aren't inadvertantly trying to print `userData[2]` instead of `usersData[2]`? I replaced your call to `response.out.write` with a simple print statement, `userData[2]` produced an index error while `usersData[2]` worked fine.